# Fabric-Composer on Windows 10 linux sub system?

Tags: hyperledger-composer, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Has anyone succeeded in running fabric-composer on windows 10 linux sub-system running ubuntu 16.04 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run composer on windows 10 WSL (windows Subsystem for linux) but you will not be able to run docker containers in it. Linux Docker containers require a linux kernel and WSL doesn't have a linux kernel. It is a clever piece of technology that converts user space Linux API calls dynamically to windows API calls.

Therefore you will have to run hyperledger fabric either by using docker for windows (which runs it for you in hyper-v) or you run your own hypervisor.

It is possible to have the docker commands run in WSL but it will need to configure it to interact with the docker daemon running inside a hypervisor.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Hyperledger-fabric-composer on windows 10, but as david said in above answer you will not be able to run docker containers directly from Ubuntu sub-system.

To do that you have to do following things:

***METHOD:- 1***

You will need to install **docker CE Client** & **docker-compose** in Ubuntu Subsystem and install **Docker(version v17.09)** on Windows as well. But those dockers won’t connect together out of the box.

So you need to expose the daemon to port **2375** first by right-clicking the docker icon on task-bar then click setting then check the Expose daemon box.

[image]

Now the docker server will be able to connect via Windows network including Ubuntu subsystem. We need to set environment variables in Ubuntu by running below command:

```
echo "export DOCKER_HOST='tcp://0.0.0.0:2375'" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

These commands will add **DOCKER_HOST** to the variables every time we start a new Bash.

***METHOD:- 2***

If you don't want to use ***ubuntu sub-system***, then you can simply install **Git Bash** and **Docker(version v17.09)**.

Then install Hyperledger-Fabric by using **Git Bash**.